# Checking if an Astyanax Keyspace is null or doesn't exist

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

Is there a way to check if an Astyanax Keyspace exists in the current context? Right now my code does the following:

```
keyspace = context.getClient();
try{
   keyspace.describeKeyspace(); 
}catch (BadRequestException e){
   keyspace.createKeyspace(ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
                .put("strategy_options", ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
                        .put("replication_factor", "1")
                        .build())
                .put("strategy_class", "SimpleStrategy")
                .build();
}
```

Is this the only way to check if the keyspace exists?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it like this...

```
try {
    keyspace.getKeyspaceProperties();
    LOG.debug("keyspace exist");
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.debug("keyspace does NOT exist");
}
```

This code will generate an exception so be sure to put some comment. If people check the log they will understand what is going on

**UPDATE**
There is a person who made a feature request on github
[Issue #382](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/issues/382).
Hope it help...

Comment: I think this is essentially what I'm doing above, but using the getKeyspaceProperties method as opposed to the describeKeyspace method. I was looking for something along the lines of
    
    if(keyspace.getKeyspaceProperties() == null){
        ...
    }